# Memory warning issue to load images in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, caching, uiimageview

I try to load images in my app asynchronously using `SDWebImage`, but it shows me memory warning & crashes the app.

I have 14 images with **4928 *X* 3280** resolution (quite big). I am load images in `UITableView` but crashes the app.

I try a lot to solve but not it is unsolved!

Help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you use [UIImage Imagename:"your image.jpg"] for this ?

Comment: please post your code at here.

Comment: Use this Library instead of `SDWebimage ` https://github.com/toptierlabs/ImageCacheResize

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?